# objective-c iPhone top level UIView blocking touch input in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, intercept

I need to have a view that is always on top (used to dither the application).  For the most part it works great, every view controller I present is displayed under this view's layer.

```
topLevelWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
if(nil == topLevelWindow)
topLevelWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];

topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, topLevelWindow.bounds.size.width, topLevelWindow.bounds.size.height)];
topView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
topView.alpha = 0.5f;
topView.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT;
topView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
[topLevelWindow addSubview:topView];
```

However, when I present the mail view controller:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

The email input form is displayed exactly as expected, under the topView layer.  However, unlike the other view controllers that I present (and I present several layers), the mail input view does not respond to touch.  Thus, the user can't send an email or even dismiss the email view controller.  The user has no option other than to kill the app.  It's like topView is intercepting all touch input.

Any ideas of what is going on?  BTW, this worked fine back in iOS 7, but does not work in iOS 9.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing `UIView` to use as your topView and override this method:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return NO;
}
```

That will make it pass through all user interaction.

**EDIT:**

On second thought, I am not sure my suggestion would help you since you are only manipulating the layer's zPosition. This actually only puts the view on top *visually*, it does not change the index of the view among the superview's subviews. This can make things a little tricky since the taps are registered by the view with the highest index, regardless of the zPosition of their layers.